# Check End of Cell Value against Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm looking to test the end of a cell's value against an array.

I found a function to test the cell value, but can't figure out how to tailor it to match only the last two digits of the cell's value.

E.g.:
**Cell A1 = A1234** needs to be checked if last two digits are in array containing **15,34**.
This should return TRUE because the last two digits **34** are in the array.

Here is the function to match the entire cell.
How would I match the end of the cell's value? (This will always be numerical, but that doesn't have to be a requirement.)

```
Sub DoSomething()
Dim Mainfram(2) As String
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

Mainfram(0) = "15"
Mainfram(1) = "34"

If IsInArray(rng.Value, Mainfram) Then
    MsgBox "Match"
End If

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
     IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: `right(rng.value,2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If IsInArray(right(rng.value,2), Mainfram) Then
 MsgBox "Match"
End If
```

Using "Right" and 2 means the right of value by 2.